# FormView does not execute the form_valid() method

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-class-based-views, django-1.11

I am using Braintree as a Payment solution (Sandbox). When I use a fill the form it redirect me to the same page. My error is that the Form doesn't get process. On the FormView only the `get_context_data()` were execute but not `form_valid()`

html

```
<script src="https://js.braintreegateway.com/web/dropin/1.6.1/js/dropin.min.js"></script>

<form action="{% url 'checkout_braintree' %}" method="POST" id="payment-form">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <h3>Method of Payment</h3>
    <p>378282246310005</p>
    <input type="hidden" id="nonce" name="payment_method_nonce" />

    <div class="bt-drop-in-wrapper">
        <div id="bt-dropin"></div>
    </div>
    <button class="button" type="submit" id="submit-button"><span>Test Transaction</span></button>
</form>
```

var form = document.querySelector('#payment-form');

```
braintree.dropin.create({
  authorization: '{{ client_token }}',
  container: '#bt-dropin',
  paypal: {
    flow: 'vault'
  }
}, function (createErr, instance) {
  form.addEventListener('submit', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    instance.requestPaymentMethod(function (err, payload) {
      if (err) {
        console.log('Error', err);
        return;
      }

      // Add the nonce to the form and submit
      document.querySelector('#nonce').value = payload.nonce;
      form.submit();
    });
  });
});
```

urls.py

```
url(r'^checkout/$',
    BraintreePaymentProcessFormView.as_view(),
    name='checkout_braintree'),
```

views.py

```
class BraintreePaymentProcessFormView(FormView):
    template_name = 'startupconfort/cart.html'
    success_url = '/'
    form_class = BraintreeSaleForm
    http_method_names  = ['post']

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        # import ipdb; ipdb.set_trace()
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['client_token'] = get_braintree_client_token()
        return context

    def form_valid(self, form):
        # import ipdb; ipdb.set_trace()
        user = self.request.user
        nonce = form.cleaned_data['payment_method_nonce']

        result = braintree.Transaction.sale({
            "amount": get_total_price_of_the_shipping_cart(user),
            "payment_method_nonce": nonce,
            "options": {
                "submit_for_settlement": True
            }
        })

        # import ipdb; ipdb.set_trace()
        if result.is_success or result.transaction:
            print(result.transaction)
            messages.success(self.request, 'Payment proceed successfully')
            # Add Total into db with User Name and Product  + Quantity

            #send email
            user = self.request.user
            billing_email = user.shipping_address.billing_email
            customer_name = user.shipping_address.customer_name
            #total values
            #msg

            # Email with mailjet..
            msg = EmailMultiAlternatives(
                subject="Please activate your account",
                body="Click to activate your account: http://localhost:8000/",
                from_email="Example <admin@example.com>",
                to=[
                    "New User <user1@example.com>"
                    ],
                reply_to=["Helpdesk <support@example.com>"]
            )

            # Send it:
            # msg.send()

            #Clear Cart
            CartItem.objects.filter(customer=user).all().delete()
            # return super().form_valid(form)
            import ipdb; ipdb.set_trace()
            return reverse_lazy('my_shopping_cart')
        else:
            print(result.errors)
            messages.success(self.request, 'An error occured while processing the payment')
            return super().form_invalid(form)
```

Braintree sandbox credit card
[image]

form

```
from django import forms
class BraintreeSaleForm(forms.Form):
    payment_method_nonce = forms.CharField()
```

Comment: You use ajax , you have to validate ajax.

Comment: Are you sure that your form is actually valid?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your views.py will be better if  you have `form_valid` and `form_invalid` methods and also you have to edit your `success_url` similar to this.

```
class BraintreePaymentProcessFormView(FormView):
    template_name = 'startupconfort/cart.html'
    success_url = '/'
    form_class = BraintreeSaleForm
    http_method_names  = ['post']
    success_url = reverse_lazy('my_shopping_cart')

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        # import ipdb; ipdb.set_trace()
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['client_token'] = get_braintree_client_token()
        return context

    def form_valid(self, form):
        # import ipdb; ipdb.set_trace()
        user = self.request.user
        nonce = form.cleaned_data['payment_method_nonce']

        result = braintree.Transaction.sale({
            "amount": get_total_price_of_the_shipping_cart(user),
            "payment_method_nonce": nonce,
            "options": {
                "submit_for_settlement": True
            }
        })
        reverse_lazy('my_shopping_cart')
        # import ipdb; ipdb.set_trace()
        if result.is_success or result.transaction:
            print(result.transaction)
            messages.success(self.request, 'Payment proceed successfully')
            # Add Total into db with User Name and Product  + Quantity

            #send email
            user = self.request.user
            billing_email = user.shipping_address.billing_email
            customer_name = user.shipping_address.customer_name
            #total values
            #msg

            # Email with mailjet..
            msg = EmailMultiAlternatives(
                subject="Please activate your account",
                body="Click to activate your account: http://localhost:8000/",
                from_email="Example <admin@example.com>",
                to=[
                    "New User <user1@example.com>"
                    ],
                reply_to=["Helpdesk <support@example.com>"]
            )

            # Send it:
            # msg.send()

            #Clear Cart
            CartItem.objects.filter(customer=user).all().delete()
            # return super().form_valid(form)
            import ipdb; ipdb.set_trace()      
        return HttpResponseRedirect(self.get_success_url()) 

        def form_invalid(self,form):
        # Add action to invalid form phase
            messages.success(self.request, 'An error occured while processing the payment')
            return self.render_to_response(self.get_context_data(form=form))
```